# Django left outer join with filter

Tags: sql, django, join

I'm using Django's built-in user model and have a custom Foo object with a ForeignKey to User. I'm looking to select all User objects and all of the Foo objects that fit certain constraints, like so:

```
SELECT * from auth_user LEFT OUTER JOIN "foo" ON
(auth_user.id = foo.id AND <other criteria here>)
```

How should I accomplish this in Django? So far I've tried:

```
User.objects.filter(foo__<criteria>)
```

but that generates SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT * from auth_user LEFT OUTER JOIN "foo" ON
(auth_user.id = foo.id) WHERE <other criteria here>
```

and only returns User objects that have Foo objects that fit the criteria. Alternately I can select all User objects and run a query for each one, but that would be substantially less efficient.

Comment: What is the other criteria? Is it all still related to the `Foo` model?

Comment: Yes. Foo contains a couple date fields and I'm only picking Foos from a specified date range.

Comment: What is `User.objects.filter(foo__<criteria>)` supposed to do?  `foo` is not field in the `User` model.  I've never been able to generate a query that has `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted Django to fetch all the `User` objects and all the `Foo` objects that are related to a user object, then you'd use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related):

```
User.objects.all().select_related('foo')
```

but here you don't want *all* the `Foo` objects that are related to a user object, you just want the subset of them that satisfy your criteria. I don't know of a way to tell Django to do that in a single query set. But what you *can* do is to do both selects separately and do the join in Python:

```
# Map from user id to corresponding Foo satisfying <criteria>, if any.
foos = {foo.user_id: foo for foo in 
        Foo.objects.filter(user__isnull = False, <criteria>)}
for user in User.objects.all():
    foo = foos.get(user.id)
    # ...
```

(This doesn't do any more database work or transfer any more data than your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would, so I think it's a reasonable approach.)

Comment: Remember that I don't actually know how your models are related, so you might have to adjust my proposed solution a bit to meet your needs.

Comment: Your solution runs this query: SELECT ••• FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = <id> for every user that has a Foo fitting the criteria. As far as I can tell, this has to do with "{foo.user_id: foo"; replacing either part with something else causes the queries to not be run. The only relation between the two models is that Foo has a ForeignKey pointing to User.

Comment: When you make a `ForeignKey` field, that usually causes two properties to be added to instances. For example, if the model `Foo` has a field `user = ForeignKey(auth_user)` I would expect `Foo` instances to have two properties: `user` (which issues a select query to fetch the related object, as you say) and `user_id` (which does not). At least, that's what I observe when running my own tests. I'm afraid you'll have to do some of your own debugging here.

Comment: I found the problem, I'd previously added user.username to Foo's __unicode__(self). Entirely my fault, your solution works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: except with this solution you need to iterate through all the user which is not always desirable. E.g. when you paginate in template by using django-endless-pagination.

Comment: Doing the join in python is *never* the right answer :-(

Comment: @ChrisWithers: If it's *never* the right answer, then what exactly do you recommend in this case? How would you solve the OP's problem?

Comment: @GarethRees - honestly? Another ORM, it's pretty disappointing that Django's ORM doesn't natively support outer joins in any kind of sensible fashion. If you have to stick with Django, like I did, look at objects.raw() and write the query properly.

Comment: @ChrisWithers: I look forward to seeing your answer.

Comment: @GarethRees - see below

Answer (score 19):

To get a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you can go:

```
User.objects.select_related('foo').filter(Q(foo__isnull=True) | Q(<other criteria here>))
```

Django uses the `foo__isnull=True` to direct it to generate a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Giving `foo__isnull=False` to generates an `INNER JOIN` as it would without the filter parameter.

Comment: Thanks for adding this.

Answer (score 8):

Django 2.0 introduced [`FilteredRelation` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects), which can produce pretty much exactly the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query you mentioned with code similar to:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    filtered_foo=FilteredRelation('foo', condition=Q(foo_<criteria>))
).values(...) # e.g. 'user__id', 'filtered_foo__id'
```

However, it looks like you need to explicitly ask for the fields of `filtered_foo` that you want to use, either by specifying in `values` or with additional annotations. Alternatively, you can also aggregate over fields of `filtered_foo` grouped by the User.

Answer (score 0):

It's clunky, but this should do it:

```
User.objects.raw('SELECT auth_user.* from auth_user LEFT OUTER JOIN '
                 '"foo" ON (auth_user.id = foo.id AND '
                 '<other criteria here>)')
```

You can splat extra attributes on the returned User objects by adding them to the left side of the select.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are good answers which may satisfy one's needs the best practice would be

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


User.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch(<related_name>, queryset=Foo.objects.filter(<criteria>)))
```

<related_name> = 'foo' if:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='foo')
```

This returns all users and foo objects related to users with the given filter criteria.