# How to express a sqlite LEFT OUTER JOIN in Django 1.9?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to select a number of `Content` objects and their related `Vote` value for a particular user, or "0" if a `Content` object doesn't have a related `Vote` value for that user. The (simplified) models look like this

```
class Content(models.Model):
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=choices, null=False)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, default=0)

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='votes', null=False)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, related_name='votes', null=False)
    value = models.SmallIntegerField(null=False)  # either 1 or -1
```

It's a simple LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQLite that attaches the fields `is_upvote` and `is_downvote` to the `Content` objects, depending on the `Vote` value it found.

```
SELECT c.id, c.points, 
    COALESCE((v.value == 1), 0) AS is_upvote, 
    COALESCE((v.value == -1), 0) AS is_downvote 
FROM pgm4app_content c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pgm4app_vote v ON v.content_id = c.id AND v.user_id=1 
WHERE c.content_type='q';
```

Is there a way to express this in Django? I found [this answer from 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15624439/5520354) that recommended doing two separate lookups and then joining it in Python. Has the Django ORM changed since then?

Joining it in Python would look somewhat like this

```
c = Content.objects.filter(content_type='q')
v = {obj.user_id: obj.value for obj in Vote.objects.filter(user=1, content__in=c)}
for obj in c:
    obj.is_upvote = v.get(obj.id, 0) == 1
    obj.is_downvote = v.get(obj.id, 0) == -1
```

Comment: Where will you use the output? in templaes?

Comment: Yes, maybe in views too. But I am also asking out of curiosity, because I didn't succeed to express this in Django ORM, to see if it is at all possible.

Comment: I was thinking of applying filter after getting all the records.
That is can be done in templates and views too.

Comment: Since you already have the query just send to raw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can do this through the ORM in newer versions of Django - see the [documentation on conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Case, When, Sum, Q

Content.objects.all().annotate(
    num_votes=Sum(Case(
            When(Q(votes__user__pk=1) & Q(votes__value=1), then=1),
            When(Q(votes__user__pk=1) & Q(votes__value=-1), then=-1),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
    )
```

The SQL query that this generates is something like:

```
SELECT "myapp_content"."id", "myapp_content"."points", 
SUM(CASE WHEN ("myapp_vote"."user_id" = 1 AND "myapp_vote"."value" = 1) THEN 1 
WHEN ("myapp_vote"."user_id" = 1 AND "myapp_vote"."value" = -1) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) 
AS "num_votes" FROM "myapp_content" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_vote" ON ("myapp_content"."id" = "myapp_vote"."content_id") 
GROUP BY "myapp_content"."id", "myapp_content"."points"
```

Instead of two properties `is_upvote` and `is_downvote` this instead returns one property `num_votes` which is either `0`, `1` or `-1` depending on how the user has voted. This can be trivially converted into two properties in Python.

(I am sure it must be possible to generate two properties in the database but my first attempt at that failed!).

Comment: Awesome, I was playing around with `Case(When())` before, but didn't quite get there.

Comment: However, the above query isn't working correctly yet. It returns more than one instance of a `Content` object, one instance for every related `Vote` object, seemingly ignoring the `votes__user__pk` restriction.

Comment: @C14L I've edited the answer to take a different approach that (I'm reasonably sure) works and does not provide duplicates. The previous approach does indeed return multiple rows.